# No Json serializer found

Tags: scala, playframework

I am doing the sample Play project from https://www.playframework.com/. I have reproduced the code from the tutorial.

However, on this code from the controller `Application`:

```
  def getPersons = Action {
    val persons = DB.query[Person].fetch
    Ok(Json.toJson(persons))
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
No Json serializer found for type Stream[models.Person with sorm.Persisted]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

But I think this shouldn't be the case, because an implicit format for this type is already implemented in the model `Person`:

```
case class Person(name: String) {

  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}
```

And this model is imported in the controller `Application`.

Is the implicit `Format` not well defined?

Comment: `Format[Person]` is not `Format[Person with Persisted]`. Try `stream.map[Person](identity)` before JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`personFormat` needs to be in a companion object for `Person`, not the `Person` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

the json format for `Person` should be in a companion object, and you have it on the (case) class :)